# Windows Azure Web Role Log files

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, azure-configuration

Is there a simple way to trace or write some log in a ASP.Net MVC3 Azure Web Role ?
I just want to write some informations and look in a log file if they were printed.
Like : WriteLine("Start Function A");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a way to get to these trace statements outside of Windows Azure, and the way Windows Azure handles this is through its diagnostics monitor. All tracing then gets routed to a table (WADLogsTable), and you can then query this table either from the role instance itself or from an app running outside of Windows Azure (by doing Linq queries, maybe Cerebrata's [Diagnostic Manager](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/), etc.). This table will aggregate log output from all your role instances.

One of my teammates, Greg Oliver, recently [blogged](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/golive/archive/2012/04/21/windows-azure-diagnostics-from-the-ground-up.aspx) about the basics.

Comment: I looked at your teammate blob but I don't understand the way it works. It seems that de 2nd solution is the best but I don't understand the way it works.

Comment: Then I suggest looking at the Windows Azure article [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/). It's actually very simple to use, and if you try it out, even in the emulator, I think you'll quickly be up to speed with it.